# How to Select all records from table 1 and exclude matching records from table 2 using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select all records from table 1 and if there any match between table 1 and table 2 then I have to exclude that records.

**Note:** The requirement is I have to use left outer join for that..

For example,

```
table 1    table 2
1           1
2           2
3
```

Output should be 3

I have written query in SQL but I want this in SQL LINQ like from a in dbContext.Table1....

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Code = t2.Code 
where s.ID is null
```

How to solve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: Only tag the technology you want your solution in i.e. LINQ **not** SQL Server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from primer in one
                     join  primer2 in two on primer.id equals primer2.id into gj
                     where gj.Count()==0
                     select new
                     {
                         primer.id
                     }).ToList();
```

Where ONE - it is first table, TWO - it is second table.
Instead of

```
...select new
                     {
                         primer.id
                     }...
```

You can use

```
...
select primer
...
```